# prove why RSA requires the use of distinct primes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help proving why RSA requires the use of distinct primes.

What I have done so far:

I figured since I need to prove why RSA requires the use if distinct primes I am going to disprove the following:

if

- p and q are the same number,
- n = pq
- c and are positive integers such that : cd is congruent to 1(mod (p-1)(q-1))
- 0<= M < n
- M^e is congruent to c(mod n), and
- c^d is congruent to r(mod n) where 0<= r < n,

then r=m

from here on out I am stuck, someone please help!

Comment: Basically the Euler toulent value of $p^2$ is not the same as that of $p\cdot q$ with $q$ replaced by $p$.

Comment: wouldn't it be a very bad idea to use the same public as private key?

Answer (score 2):

One simple suggestion could be that it's very fast to find a square root if it exists (by "exists", I mean "exists and in the integers"). So an algorithm for cracking RSA could just start with that.

Comment: ^^ That's true...but I rather prove the statement by disproving the opposite because that is more convincing and concise.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: ok. But still, how would I disprove my above proposition?

Comment: Im not sure that you can. There may be multiple solutions, but the point would be that they'd be easy to find, and then, since there won't be that many (maybe at most four due to the square rooting?) then you can just try all four. Three will give decode to give nonsensical rubbish, but the other one will give a sensible solution.